# Open Browser window from Java program

Tags: java, linux, browser, x11, daemon

**Question**

I have an application written in Java.  It is designed to run on a Linux box standalone.  I am trying to spawn a new *firefox* window.  However, *firefox* never opens.  It always has a shell exit code of 1.  I can run this same code with *gnome-terminal* and it opens fine.

**Background**

So, here is its initialization process:

1. Start X "Xorg :1 -br -terminate -dpms -quiet vt7"
2. Start Window Manager "metacity --display=:1 --replace"
3. Configure resources "xrdb -merge /etc/X11/Xresources"
4. Become a daemon and disconnect from controlling terminal

Once the program is up an running, there is a button the user can click that should spawn a firefox window.  Here is my code to do that.  Remember X is running on display :1.

**Code**

```
public boolean openBrowser()
{
  try {
    Process oProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "/usr/bin/firefox --display=:1" );
    int bExit = oProc.waitFor();  // This is always 1 for some reason

    return true;

  } catch ( Exception e ) {
    oLogger.log( Level.WARNING, "Open Browser", e );
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right.  Somehow I posted it before I was finished typing.  It should be there in full now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after having read the various answers and various comments(from questioner), here's what I would do

1) try this java approach
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
env.remove("OTHERVAR");
env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
pb.directory("myDir");
Process p = pb.start();
```

see more about this class:

http://java.sun.com/developer/JDCTechTips/2005/tt0727.html#2 
http://www.javabeat.net/tips/8-using-the-new-process-builder-class.html

2) try doing this(launching firefox) from C/C++/ruby/python and see if that is succeeding.

3) if all else fails, I would launch a shell program and that shell program would launch firefox!!

Comment: This worked.  As it turns out, since I am not running a Desktop environment, I had to set the HOME environment variable for firefox to run properly.

Answer (score 9):

If you can narrow it down to Java 6, you can use the desktop API:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/

Should look something like:

```
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            try {
                desktop.browse(new URI("http://localhost"));
            }
            catch(IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(URISyntaxException use) {
                use.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried using this, but I get a traceback.

<pre><code>
java.io.IOException: Failed to show URI:
        at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.launch(XDesktopPeer.java:75)
        at sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.browse(XDesktopPeer.java:64)
        at java.awt.Desktop.browse(Desktop.java:368)
</code></pre>

Answer (score 4):

Use [BrowserLauncher](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/).

Invoking it is very easy, just go

```
new BrowserLauncher().openURLinBrowser("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck if you read and display the standard output/error streams, so you can catch any error message firefox may print.

Comment: I cannot seem to get any output from firefox.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
     String url = "http://www.google.com";
     java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```