# Can Java's Desktop.browse provide an HTML Target in order to reuse a browser window?

Tags: java, browser, javahelp

I'm moving an application from using javax.help's browser to the user's desktop web browser, but I'm wondering how to prevent the user from winding up with many windows/tabs open as they click to different parts of the document.  I don't see any way to specify an HTML Target in a java URI or a call to Desktop.browse.  Is there any way to do this in Java within (or outside) Desktop.browse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no support for this.

Instead, you can open a unique HTML document which display links to other documents. Links will be opened within the browser without opening new window/tab.

Comment: If the user were moving over to the browser to open various links there, that would be fine, but I need the user to be able to launch various links from the java application.  I think you're right that this is unsupported.

Comment: Incidentally, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248534/open-browser-window-from-java-program mentions BrowserLauncher2 which also does not support it.  Perhaps it's impractical to implement in any browser-general way.  (I'd be happy to hear if there's, say, a perl or python library that can do it.)