# using java to open a new tab in the same browser

Tags: java, session, browser

Basically, I have encountered a problem when opening a new window when I developing my project. I don't want to use JavaScript's window.open().

I am using jsf+spring+hibernate framework. When the user login to the system(employing spring security), two pages are shown, one is on the original tab, another one must be  a popup. I've found a way to open a new browser. Here it is:

```
public class LaunchBlackBoard {
public static void runBrowser(String webSite) {
    try {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()
                && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
            URI uri = new URI(webSite);
            desktop.browse(uri);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the problem. This class is used to open the default browser but not the current running browser. If the user uses the non-default browser to login, then the default browser will open. If this is the case, because of the session problem, the new tab will not be authenticated due to the missing session.

Right now, I want to find a way that either can open a new tab in the same browser or passing the session object from one browser to another. Any good idea? thanks a lot.

Comment: And you'd want it to be a cross-browser solution ? I don't think there could be a reasonable solution without javascript. Why don't you want to use `window.open()` ?

Comment: Is this a web application (I think so, looking at JSF)? If so, you are calling a java method to open a browser window for an action on your web page/webapp?

Comment: Is the class 'Desktop' from AWT? If yes, it can't work as web application.

Comment: I think some users may not want to allow the js behavior.

Comment: @Vikdor yes, anything not good?

Comment: @user1606528 yes, and it really works well except opening the default browser

Comment: @Deacon_MENG, consider the scenario where the serverside code runs on machine A and a client opened your web application on machine B, this use case would open the browser on Machine A and not on B, for obvious reasons. You HAVE to use javascript to open the URL and you don't have a handle on whether the URL will be opened in a tab or a window. That is very much a user-specific setting on which the webapp developers don't have any control, at least for now.

Comment: @Vikdor *"That is very much a user-specific setting on which the webapp developers don't have any control, at least for now."*  And a good thing too.  User rules!  :)

Comment: @Vikdor I think I got the point. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, true, I would hate if a webapp opens a link in a window when i configured all links to be in tabs and viceversa :)

Comment: @Vikdor I am still waiting on `User.getBrain().getThoughtsAsList()`...

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method to open the new tab in same browesr. We can find the current browser by using the Httprequest.

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
if (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {
  out.println("Your browser is Microsoft Internet Explorer<br/>");
}
```

http://www.codemiles.com/servlets-jsp/how-can-we-get-browser-information-in-jsp-t1286.html

based on the this selection we can start the new browser as new process

[Open Browser window from Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248534/open-browser-window-from-java-program)